# Check if restaurant is open or closed C# with multiple opening/closing times

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a scenario in which a restaurant can have multiple opening/closing times, and the closing-time can be passed mid-night in some cases.

Something like this:

```
Day - [Monday] - Open Time - [09:00] - Close Time - [18:00]
Day - [Monday] - Open Time - [22:00] - Close Time - [02:00]

Day - [Tuesday] - Open Time - [12:00] - Close Time - [23:59]

Day - [Wednesday] - Open Time - [09:00] - Close Time - [18:00]
Day - [Wednesday] - Open Time - [22:00] - Close Time - [02:00]

Day - [Thursday] - Open Time - [14:00] - Close Time - [02:00]

Day - [Friday] - Open Time - [16:00] - Close Time - [02:00]

Day - [Saturday] - Open Time - [12:00] - Close Time - [01:00]

Day - [Sunday] - Open Time - [12:00] - Close Time - [01:59]
```

I need to check if the restaurant is opened or closed at the time of request, this is what I have got so far (Posting entire code with sample data - you can paste in a C# Console App and run it):

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var restaurantList = new RestaurantTimingList();


        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------RESTAURANT TIMINGS -----------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------");

        foreach (var timing in restaurantList.Timings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Day - [{0}] - Open Time - [{1}] - Close Time - [{2}]", timing.Day, timing.OpenTimeString, timing.CloseTimeString);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------");

        var time = "01:01";

        var dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday;

        Console.WriteLine("Day - [{0}] - Time - [{1}] - IsOpen - [{2}]", dayOfWeek, time, restaurantList.CheckIsOpen(dayOfWeek, time));
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------");

        time = "01:00";
        Console.WriteLine("Day - [{0}] - Time - [{1}] - IsOpen - [{2}]", dayOfWeek, time, restaurantList.CheckIsOpen(dayOfWeek, time));
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------");

        dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Tuesday;
        time = "00:00";
        Console.WriteLine("Day - [{0}] - Time - [{1}] - IsOpen - [{2}]", dayOfWeek, time, restaurantList.CheckIsOpen(dayOfWeek, time));
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------");

        time = "23:58";
        Console.WriteLine("Day - [{0}] - Time - [{1}] - IsOpen - [{2}]", dayOfWeek, time, restaurantList.CheckIsOpen(dayOfWeek, time));
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}


public class RestaurantTiming
{
    public int TimingId { get; set; }
    public DayOfWeek Day { get; set; }

    public string OpenTimeString { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan OpenTime { get; set; }

    public string CloseTimeString { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan CloseTime { get; set; }

    public RestaurantTiming(int timingId, DayOfWeek day, string openTime, string closeTime)
    {
        TimingId = timingId;
        Day = day;

        OpenTimeString = openTime;
        OpenTime = TimeSpan.Parse(openTime);

        CloseTimeString = closeTime;
        CloseTime = TimeSpan.Parse(closeTime);
    }
}

public class RestaurantTimingList
{
    public List<RestaurantTiming> Timings { get; set; }

    public RestaurantTimingList()
    {
        Timings = new List<RestaurantTiming>();

        Timings.Add(new RestaurantTiming(1, DayOfWeek.Monday, "09:00", "18:00"));
        Timings.Add(new RestaurantTiming(2, DayOfWeek.Monday, "22:00", "02:00"));

        Timings.Add(new RestaurantTiming(3, DayOfWeek.Tuesday, "12:00", "23:59"));

        Timings.Add(new RestaurantTiming(4, DayOfWeek.Wednesday, "09:00", "18:00"));
        Timings.Add(new RestaurantTiming(5, DayOfWeek.Wednesday, "22:00", "02:00"));

        Timings.Add(new RestaurantTiming(6, DayOfWeek.Thursday, "14:00", "02:00"));

        Timings.Add(new RestaurantTiming(7, DayOfWeek.Friday, "16:00", "02:00"));

        Timings.Add(new RestaurantTiming(8, DayOfWeek.Saturday, "12:00", "01:00"));

        Timings.Add(new RestaurantTiming(9, DayOfWeek.Sunday, "12:00", "01:59"));
    }

    public bool CheckIsOpen(DayOfWeek weekDay, string time)
    {
        var timeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(time);
        // Group By Day Of week - 
        var grouped = Timings.GroupBy(s => s.Day).ToList();

        // Get All timings of the day
        var weekDayTimings = grouped.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key == weekDay);

        // No Weekday found - Restaurant closed on this return false
        if (weekDayTimings == null) return false;

        // Check passed time to see if is in Any of the timings of that Day
        foreach (var timing in weekDayTimings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Open [{1}] - Close [{2}] -  ", weekDay, timing.OpenTimeString, timing.CloseTimeString);

            var start = timing.OpenTime;
            var end = timing.CloseTime;
            var now = timeSpan;

            if (start <= end)
            {
                // start and stop times are in the same day
                if (now >= start && now <= end)
                {
                    // current time is between start and stop
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // start and stop times are in different days
                if (now >= start || now <= end)
                {
                    // current time is between start and stop
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

### The Problem

I am going to try to explain it with an example:

The restaurant is open on `Monday from 10:00 PM - 02:00 AM` - so the time moves onto the next day - (Which means that the restaurant is open on Tuesday from `00:00 AM - 02:00 AM`)

Now let's say a user makes a request on: `Tuesday 01:00 AM`

Like this:

```
 dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Tuesday; // What will actually be here DateTime.Now.Day;
 time = "01:00";  // What will actually be here: DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
 Console.WriteLine("Day - [{0}] - Time - [{1}] - IsOpen - [{2}]", dayOfWeek, time, restaurantList.CheckIsOpen(dayOfWeek, time));
```

Now this returns `FALSE` (Restaurant is NOT open) - But because the timing on `Monday is till 02:00 AM` this should return true.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just set up the restaurant to say it is open on Monday from 10pm to midnight and then on Tuesday from midnight to 2am instead?  What I'm saying is that setting it up as Monday 10pm to 2am is invalid.

Comment: Exactly, the restaurant is technically open Monday from 10:00 PM - until Tuesday 02:00 AM isnt it?

Comment: @juharr that is what is actually happening - but the data saved to the DB is like the data i showed in the sample -

Comment: @JFM yes that is correct

Comment: @DawoodAwan Then I would suggest you fix the data in the database instead.  That or split the times when you read it from the DB and create your objects.

Comment: Problem is, that in your data Saturday 01:00 means Sunday 01:00 and when you query for Saturday 01:00 I assume you mean exactly Saturday 01:00. So you should convert both values to comparable type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed a little bit your logic.

Let restaurant timing decide when it match to time and when not

```
public class RestaurantTiming
{
    public int TimingId { get; set; }
    public Interval[] Intervals { get; set;}

    public string OpenTimeString { get; private set; }
    public string CloseTimeString { get; private set; }

    public RestaurantTiming(int timingId, DayOfWeek day, string openTime, string closeTime)
    {
        TimingId = timingId;
        OpenTimeString = openTime;
        CloseTimeString = closeTime;

        var intervals = new List<Interval>();


        var openTimeParsed = TimeSpan.Parse(openTime);      
        var closeTimeParsed = TimeSpan.Parse(closeTime);

        if (closeTimeParsed > openTimeParsed)
        {
            intervals.Add(new Interval() { Day = day, CloseTime = closeTimeParsed, OpenTime = openTimeParsed });
        }
        else
        {
            intervals.Add(new Interval() { Day = day, CloseTime = new TimeSpan(23,59,59), OpenTime = openTimeParsed });
            intervals.Add(new Interval() { Day = NextDayOfWeek(day), CloseTime = closeTimeParsed, OpenTime = new TimeSpan(0,0,0) });
        }       

        Intervals = intervals.ToArray();
    }

    public bool IsMatch(DayOfWeek day, TimeSpan span)
    {
        return Intervals.Any(x=>x.Day == day && x.OpenTime <= span && x.CloseTime >= span);
    }

    public class Interval
    {
        public DayOfWeek Day { get; set; }      
        public TimeSpan OpenTime { get; set; }      
        public TimeSpan CloseTime { get; set; }
    }

    private DayOfWeek NextDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek current)
    {
        return NextDays[current];
    }

    private static Dictionary<DayOfWeek, DayOfWeek> NextDays = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, DayOfWeek>()
        {
            {DayOfWeek.Sunday, DayOfWeek.Monday},
            { DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Tuesday},
            { DayOfWeek.Tuesday, DayOfWeek.Wednesday},
            { DayOfWeek.Wednesday, DayOfWeek.Thursday},
            { DayOfWeek.Thursday, DayOfWeek.Friday},
            { DayOfWeek.Friday, DayOfWeek.Saturday},
            { DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday}
        };
}
```

In that case Timing list will be simpler

```
public class RestaurantTimingList
{
    public List<RestaurantTiming> Timings { get; set; }

    public RestaurantTimingList()
    {
        Timings = new List<RestaurantTiming>();

        Timings.Add(new RestaurantTiming(1, DayOfWeek.Monday, "09:00", "18:00"));
        Timings.Add(new RestaurantTiming(2, DayOfWeek.Monday, "22:00", "02:00"));

        Timings.Add(new RestaurantTiming(3, DayOfWeek.Tuesday, "12:00", "23:59"));

        Timings.Add(new RestaurantTiming(4, DayOfWeek.Wednesday, "09:00", "18:00"));
        Timings.Add(new RestaurantTiming(5, DayOfWeek.Wednesday, "22:00", "02:00"));

        Timings.Add(new RestaurantTiming(6, DayOfWeek.Thursday, "14:00", "02:00"));

        Timings.Add(new RestaurantTiming(7, DayOfWeek.Friday, "16:00", "02:00"));

        Timings.Add(new RestaurantTiming(8, DayOfWeek.Saturday, "12:00", "01:00"));

        Timings.Add(new RestaurantTiming(9, DayOfWeek.Sunday, "12:00", "01:59"));
    }

    public bool CheckIsOpen(DayOfWeek weekDay, string time)
    {
        return Timings.Any(x=>x.IsMatch(weekDay, TimeSpan.Parse(time)));
    }

}
```

And we have to apply minimal changes to Main

```
void Main()
{
    var restaurantList = new RestaurantTimingList();

    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------RESTAURANT TIMINGS -----------------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------");

    foreach (var timing in restaurantList.Timings.SelectMany(x=>x.Intervals))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Day - [{0}] - Open Time - [{1}] - Close Time - [{2}]", timing.Day, timing.OpenTime, timing.CloseTime);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------");

    var time = "01:01";

    var dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday;

    Console.WriteLine("Day - [{0}] - Time - [{1}] - IsOpen - [{2}]", dayOfWeek, time, restaurantList.CheckIsOpen(dayOfWeek, time));
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------");

    time = "01:00";
    Console.WriteLine("Day - [{0}] - Time - [{1}] - IsOpen - [{2}]", dayOfWeek, time, restaurantList.CheckIsOpen(dayOfWeek, time));
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------");

    dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Tuesday;
    time = "00:00";
    Console.WriteLine("Day - [{0}] - Time - [{1}] - IsOpen - [{2}]", dayOfWeek, time, restaurantList.CheckIsOpen(dayOfWeek, time));
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------");

    time = "23:58";
    Console.WriteLine("Day - [{0}] - Time - [{1}] - IsOpen - [{2}]", dayOfWeek, time, restaurantList.CheckIsOpen(dayOfWeek, time));
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------");

    Console.ReadKey();  
}
```

And output

```
---------------------------------RESTAURANT TIMINGS -----------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
Day - [Monday] - Open Time - [09:00:00] - Close Time - [18:00:00]
Day - [Monday] - Open Time - [22:00:00] - Close Time - [23:59:59]
Day - [Tuesday] - Open Time - [00:00:00] - Close Time - [02:00:00]
Day - [Tuesday] - Open Time - [12:00:00] - Close Time - [23:59:00]
Day - [Wednesday] - Open Time - [09:00:00] - Close Time - [18:00:00]
Day - [Wednesday] - Open Time - [22:00:00] - Close Time - [23:59:59]
Day - [Thursday] - Open Time - [00:00:00] - Close Time - [02:00:00]
Day - [Thursday] - Open Time - [14:00:00] - Close Time - [23:59:59]
Day - [Friday] - Open Time - [00:00:00] - Close Time - [02:00:00]
Day - [Friday] - Open Time - [16:00:00] - Close Time - [23:59:59]
Day - [Saturday] - Open Time - [00:00:00] - Close Time - [02:00:00]
Day - [Saturday] - Open Time - [12:00:00] - Close Time - [23:59:59]
Day - [Sunday] - Open Time - [00:00:00] - Close Time - [01:00:00]
Day - [Sunday] - Open Time - [12:00:00] - Close Time - [23:59:59]
Day - [Monday] - Open Time - [00:00:00] - Close Time - [01:59:00]
---------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
Day - [Saturday] - Time - [01:01] - IsOpen - [True]
---------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
Day - [Saturday] - Time - [01:00] - IsOpen - [True]
---------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
Day - [Tuesday] - Time - [00:00] - IsOpen - [True]
---------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
Day - [Tuesday] - Time - [23:58] - IsOpen - [True]
---------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
```

Edit:
I pointed end of day as `new TimeSpan(24,59,59)`, but if it is matter for you to check exactly 00:00, you can replace it with `new TimeSpan(24,0,0)`

Comment: I love this answer. I appreciate the effort you put into it too. Thanks.

Comment: @SubliminalHash I'm glad that it was useful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to get what you want!

1. As suggested in comments, you can create a new table (either manually , if allowed, or by code!)that has opening and closing time for every day. hence, if  time is 22:00 to 02:00 for Monday, your new table will have 22:00 to 23:59 Monday and 00:00 to 02:00 Tuesday.

This will simplify your problem and give correct output with your code.

2. If you do not want to go with the above solution, you can do this: 
   check opening and closing times of previous day to see if they are open after midnight as well.

hope this helps! :)